# ADODB : Not able to save file after dowload

Tags: vba, excel, ado

I am using the code below to download PDF files from a website and then I want to save them in local drive.

I am trying to save files using ***oStream.SaveToFile*** method but files are being downloaded in corrupted format error. Or when I'm using ***oStream.Save*** method, files are not being downloaded at all. Please help.

```
Sub login()
    Dim objIE As InternetExplorer
    Dim uid As String
    Dim pwd As String
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim objCollection As Object
    Dim buttonCollection As Object
    Dim ieElement As Object
    Dim ieButton As Object
    Dim WinHttpReq As Object
    Dim oStream As Object
    Dim MyURL As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    Set sh = Sheets("Indeed Resume Download")
    Set rng = sh.Range("A2")

    If Trim(rng.Value) = "" Or Trim(rng.Offset(0, 1).Value) = "" Then
        MsgBox "User ID And Password are mandatory."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    On Error Resume Next
    objIE.Quit
    Set objIE = Nothing
    On Error GoTo 0

    uid = rng.Value
    pwd = rng.Offset(0, 1).Value

    Dim j As Long

    Set objIE = New InternetExplorer 'Initialize internet object
    objIE.Navigate "https://secure.indeed.com/account/login?service=my&hl=en_IN&co=IN&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.indeed.co.in%2F"
    objIE.Visible = True

    With objIE
        Do While .Busy: Loop
        Do While .ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: Loop
        Do While .Busy: Loop
    End With

    objIE.Document.all.signin_email.Value = uid
    objIE.Document.all.signin_password.Value = pwd

    Set ieElement = objIE.Document.getElementsByClassName("sg-btn sg-btn-primary btn-signin")(0)

    ieElement.Click

    For j = 2 To sh.Cells(Rows.Count, 27).End(xlUp).Row

        Set objIE = New InternetExplorer
        objIE.Visible = True

        Dim Sender As String
        MyURL = sh.Range("XDA" & j).Value
        Sender = sh.Range("XDB" & j).Value

        objIE.Navigate MyURL

        Do While objIE.Busy = True
            DoEvents
        Loop

        Do While objIE.Busy: Loop
        Do While objIE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: Loop
        Do While objIE.Busy: Loop

        On Error Resume Next
        Set ieButton = objIE.Document.getElementsByClassName("button download_button")(0)

        ieButton.Click

        WinHttpReq.Open "GET", MyURL, False
        WinHttpReq.Send

        MyURL = WinHttpReq.responseBody
        Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        oStream.Open
        oStream.Type = 1
        oStream.Write WinHttpReq.responseBody
        oStream.Save ("D:\Downloaded Indeed Resume - Store")
        'oStream.SaveToFile ("D:\Downloaded Indeed Resume - Store\" & Sender & ".pdf"), adSaveCreateOverWrite
        oStream.Close

    Next j    
    Set objIE = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: This is not the answer you are looking for, but I would accomplish this automation with Selenium Web Driver.

Comment: Thanks Dani Aya but this is not my requirement at this point of time.